# How do I programmatically detect errors like IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec?

Tags: android, error-handling, opengl-es-2.0

I am deliberately running an OpenGL ES 2.0 application on the emulator. While I know this is supposed to fail (and it does), I wanted to learn how I would catch the error programmatically.

I am using the HelloOpenGLES20 tutorial code, so I don't think I need to repost it here. I am using the Android 4.0.3 (version 15) code base.

In other words, how do I make my app more robust, robust enough to catch this error? (e.g., suppose I was crazy enough to want to provide both OpenGL 2.0 and 1.0 support, and fallback to the 1.0 code if I could not run the 2.0 - please don't tell me to check the API version, as that won't address how to detect this particular error)

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'd suggest against *detecting errors*. In stead the best practise is to to **test for the particular feature you'd like to use**, *preventing* the error.

In this particular case, check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);    ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();    
boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;
```

Comment: I understand and appreciate that is the better way. However, I am relatively new to Java and very new to Android programming, so when I come across an "undetectable" error, I am interested in learning (a) what makes it undetectable and (b) what one would have to do to catch the error.

Comment: Perhaps some additional elaboration would help explain my inquiry. Given the myriad possibilities to screw up a config and produce the same error, how would I detect and debug such a configuration issue? The GL 2.0 error manifests as an exception at the end of Thread.run() (if that is the right way to identify it) with no relevant or helpful stack details.